# Менять значения блока при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: html, css

Здравствуйте. Есть ссылка

```
<div class="menu">
    <a href="/">меню</a>
</div>
```

И на этой же страничке есть блок:

```
<div class="menu_block">
    //инфа
</div>
```

Значения этого блока по умолчанию

```
.menu_block {
background-color: #eaeaea;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
display: none;
}
```

Каким образом сделать, чтоб при клике на ссылку **меню** , значение *display* у блока *menu_block* менялось на block ?

Как отследить клик по ссылке или по блоку в css?

Буду благодарен за помощь!

Comment: Это просто сделать средствами JS.

Comment: @AimX может есть подобные примеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C использованием jquery можно сделать:

```js
$(function(){
  $(".menu a").click(function(){ // отлавливаем нажатие на ссылку
      $(".menu_block").css({display: 'block'}); // задаем стили
    });
  });
```

```css
.menu_block {
background-color: #eaeaea;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">меню</a>
</div>

<div class="menu_block">
    We use this domain to render user-provided code snippets. Some of our websites have enabled interactive code snippets which can be run by other users in order to see the output. This domain is used to host the results of running those snippets. We host the results on a different domain because we must prevent same-origin from being in effect. If same-origin was possible, users could write code that caused other users to do things that they didn't want to on their Stack Exchange account. What kinds of things? Evil things. Things like logging a user out, or updating their profile, or even possibly posting questions or answers! So, this domain stops bad people from doing bad things.
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

***Пример №1*** (без jQuery):

```js
function showBlockMenu() {
  document.getElementsByClassName('menu_block')[0].style.display = 'block';
}
```

```css
.menu_block {
background-color: #eaeaea;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu" onclick="showBlockMenu();">
    <a href="#">меню</a>
</div>
<div class="menu_block">
    <p> Content Menu </p>
</div>
```

***Пример №2*** (с jQuery):

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('menu')[0].addEventListener('click', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('menu_block')[0].style.display = 'block';
}, false);
```

```css
.menu_block {
background-color: #eaeaea;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 999;
display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
    <a href="#">меню</a>
</div>
<div class="menu_block">
    <p> Content Menu </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
ajax.callback = function(data){
    $('#menu').text(data.menu);
};
</script>

<a  href="#" onclick="$('#menu-open').show(); return false;">меню</a>
<div id="menu-open" style="display: none;"><span id="menu">инфа</span></div>
```